# Android telnet server, which lets me see the commands that arrive

Tags: gratis, android, telnet

I am coding an app that will Telnet in to some software that has not yet been written.

I want to test my app, but don't have admin rights at work, so I can't install the Windows (XP!) Telnet server.

Does anyone use an Android Telnet server which would let me see the commands that my app is sending, for debugging purposes?

Note that I want to connect over WiFi, not USB cable.